# what could be causing this error after yo- installing and running keystone.js?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, keystonejs

I ran the default installation for keystone and havn't altered any of the files other than connecting to my own mongodb

In my Browser I'm seeing:

Sorry, an error occurred loading the page (500)

Path must be a string. Received [ 'templates', 'templates/views' ]

```
`
zerp:keystone-yo asdf$ nodemon
[nodemon] 1.9.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node keystone.js`

------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
keystone is ready on port 3000
------------------------------------------------

Error thrown for request: /
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received [ 'templates', 'templates/views' ]
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.relative (path.js:1228:5)
    at ExpressHandlebars.renderView (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/express-handlebars/lib/express-handlebars.js:192:43)
    at View.render (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:126:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:639:10)
    at EventEmitter.render (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:591:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:960:7)
    at View.<anonymous> (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/keystone/lib/view.js:337:13)
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/keystone/lib/view.js:372:3
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:269:32
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:726:13
    at /Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at _parallel (/Users/asdf/Desktop/keystone-yo/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:717:9)
GET / 500 12.613 m`
```

Comment: @w00t `keystonejs` is a tag synonym. You don't need to add it everywhere.

Comment: @drew yes but it wasn't so we needed votes to make it a synonymn :-)

Comment: @w00t adding the synonym tag is unnecessary, it causes questions to get bumped up to the top of Active, and a user 'complained' about it elsewhere so I felt I would let you know

Comment: @drew aha, did not realize that. We were trying to get documentation accepted for keystone but the new tag was not a synonym and so we tried to increase its activity. In the end there's not enough question traffic though :-(

Comment: Come to [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) and JAL and I will take a look @w00t and approve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I found is that inside *keystone.js* the method `keystone.init()` is expecting a *String* instead of and *Array*.  Change the line that reads `'views': ['templates', 'templates/views'],` to `'views': 'templates/views',`.  Hope this fixes your issue.